# return true if a and b have the same items but not necessarily in the same order, false otherwise return false if either of array passed is null

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with this code and getting an error saying expected false but was true

```
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return true if a and b have the same items but not necessarily in the same
 *         order, false otherwise return false if either of array passed is null
 */
public boolean same(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == b)
        return true;
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;
    int length = a.length;
    if (b.length != length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (a[i] == b[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}// to be completed
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, and *ask a question*.

Comment: Take a pen and paper (or a debugger if you know how to use one), and manually try to follow your code for the following input arrays: `a = { 1, 3, 4 }` and `b = { 1, 6, 7 }`. Can you tell what's wrong?

Comment: What about duplicates? for instance, what would be the result of comparing `{ 1, 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 1, 2, 2, 3 }` ?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that came to my mind: make a copy of both arrays, sort the copies, and then compare them:

```
public static boolean same(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == b)
        return true;
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;
    int length = a.length;
    if (b.length != length)
        return false;
    int[] aa = Arrays.copyOf(a, length);
    int[] bb = Arrays.copyOf(b, length);
    Arrays.sort(aa);
    Arrays.sort(bb);
    return Arrays.equals(aa, bb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either sort the input arrays and match each value one by one. This will take O(NlogN) time and O(N) space if you can't modify the input arrays.

Or use a HashMap or similar data structure to record the occurrences of each value. This will be O(N) time and you would use additional memory O(N).

It returns true only if the occurrences of all the values are the same in each array, order doesn't matter.

```
public boolean same(int[] a, int[] b){
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        int length = a.length;
        if (b.length != length)
            return false;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Integer countA = map.getOrDefault(a[i], 0);
            map.put(a[i], countA + 1);

            Integer countB = map.getOrDefault(b[i], 0);
            map.put(b[i], countB - 1);
        }

        for(Integer x: map.values()){
            if(x != 0){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```